# how i can return more than one value from windows to unix-AIX?

Tags: unix, command-line, windows-server-2003, aix

HI, i'm have to server:- 1-windows-server 2003 2-UNIX-AIX

I execute something in windows server and now i want to return some value from windows to unix .... how i can do it

i install copssh in windows server and openssh in unix server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MQ(Message queue), Luke!